# try to use rangeOfString to behave url for youtube video

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, webview, nsstring

I need the app recognize if it's a youtube video embed, then in-app webView

Here is the code I'm using now:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
{
NSString *urlString = request.URL.absoluteString;
NSString *youtube;

youtube = @"youtube";

if ([urlString rangeOfString:youtube options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound){
    return YES;
}
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
return NO;
}
```

That works in most cases because most youtube links are directly transferred as embedded  video already on the webpage. However, I check if i choose a profile page or others from youtube, this will still open in-app, becuz my app doesn't have back button (buttons in html page). So any link that's not to a video will cause can't return. 
I tried use *@"youtube.com/watch"*  *@"/watch?"*  *@"watch?"* as rangeOfString, but only *youtube* works.

For example:
This a youtube video url: data-url="http://youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Ke1Y3P9D0Bc"  (in-app view good)

dara-url="youtube.com" (fail, still in-app view)

I wonder either i stored string by wrong format, symbols not support in rangeOfString?
Or there can be another way like `urlString rangeOfString:youtube && @"watch"`

Thank you for this, really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Ke1Y3P9D0Bc"];
NSString *host = myURL.host;
NSString *path = myURL.path;
NSLog(@"%@", host); // Output: www.youtube.com
NSLog(@"%@", path); // Output: /watch
NSLog(@"%@", myURL.query); // Output: feature=player_detailpage&v=Ke1Y3P9D0Bc
if (NSMaxRange([host rangeOfString:@"youtube.com" options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSBackwardsSearch)]) == host.length &&
    [path.lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"/watch"]) {
    NSLog(@"This is a youtube video.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use,

```
if ([urlString rangeOfString:youtube options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound && [urlString rangeOfString:@"watch" options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
```

Whether that will get you what you want, I don't know, but it should work as a valid if statement.

Comment: tks, i tried use this one before, turns out its a NSUrl path issue with embed. tks fixed it.